# How to See The Data Which Has A Hidden Form Value Or Not PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a set of input boxes and you can add more and more sets of these forms if you click the add more button. In my form I can submit data and I have got it to show up when you reload the page, when the page shows it it also adds a value into a hidden form in case the user updates this information.

However, how can I see all the sets of data which do not have a hidden form value? And all the sets with do have a hidden value so I can do different things to them.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<form>
    <div class = "fieldset-1">
        <input type="text" id="Name1" name="name[]">
        <input type="hidden" id="id1" name="id[]">
    </div>
    <div class = "fieldset-2">
        <input type="text" id="Name2" name="name[]">
        <input type="hidden" id="id2" name="id[]">
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
    $data = $_POST;

    extract($data, EXTR_PREFIX_SAME,"br");

    //Prints The Variables To Make Sure They Are Correct
    print_r($id);

    $name = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z- ]/", "", $name);
    print_r($name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have all the post data in a `$_POST`. It doesn't depend on field's type. The only thing matters — field's name.

The reason why you can't see it with your code is that you do

```
$name = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z- ]/", "", $name);
```

For what, btw? `preg_replace` is for string, `$name` here is an array (cause your form field has a name `name[]`), so function fails, and you lost your data.

And don't ever use `extract`, it's considered harmful.